# Why aren't shadows showing up?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a pretty standard scene in Three.js. There are a few objects, a ground plane, and a few directional lights, one of which casts a shadow. Most of my objects cast shadows without any problem. A few, for some reason, do not. All of the `Mesh` objects are embedded in a hierarchy of `Object3D` objects, most of which are 2 or 3 levels deep. The ones that are not casting shadows are in a more complicated hierarchy where some of the `Mesh` objects are 20+ levels deep. The hierarchy is in place to mimic a complicated hierarchy found in a simulation program I'm trying to port.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

And here it is with only the shadow-casting light enabled:

[image]

Both the guy in the yellow shirt and the orange robot in the background have this problem. They both have the complicated hierarchy. None of the stationary objects have this problem. They have the simpler, 3-level hierarchy. As you can see, the guy is nestled in between several objects that are properly casting shadows so he's definitely inside the light's shadow frustum.

I've followed the standard checklist for debugging shadows, but no luck:

- The directional light has `.castShadow` set to `true`
- Only one directional light casts a shadow
- The directional light's shadow frustum settings are correct (which you can see from the screenshot)
- Each `Mesh` object in the scene has `.castShadow` and `.receiveShadow` set to `true`
- The ground plane has `.receiveShadow` set to true
- There are no holes in the ground plane
- EDIT: When I disable all lights except the one that casts a shadow, the problem still occurs

Does a deep hierarchy mess with the `.castShadow` settings? That's the only explanation I can think of.

EDIT: Here's the depth buffer data from the directional light. Notice there's nothing that looks like our guy or our robot:

[image]

BTW, I'm running Three.js r70.

Comment: Is there any chance that the others non-shadow casting lights are acting as `Ambient Lights` although are initialy declared as `Directional`? @Justin

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. However, the problem still happens when I turn each light off, except the shadow-casting one.

Comment: Ambient lighting is defined as an uniform light source that emits light to a scene casting/or not shadows. As you could see here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading#Ambient_lighting .For your description, it sounds to me that the lights that are not casting shadows are being treated as an ambient lights. Btw, could you provide  the part of the code where you add the lights to the scene? @Justin

Comment: Here's the code: `this.scene.add(_obj.object);` this.scene is a THREE.Scene and _obj.object is a THREE.DirectionalLight. This code is buried under a layer or two of abstraction, so I'm not sure this line will be very much help for debugging.

Comment: So, you are using the same function and the same vars several times to add the lights, right? And only the first one works, true? What if, you try to make usage of an array (for example) to avoid instancing properties to the same object? Does it make sense? @Justin

Comment: Nope, the lights are each distinct objects (I called `new` for each light). Also, their constructor arguments are distinct (once again, each argument has its own `new`) I added a second screenshot where only the shadow-casting light is enabled. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Somewhere in the super-deep hierarchy, I was *accidentally* setting the `.visible` attribute of one of the placeholder `Object3D` objects to `undefined`. That suggests that WebGLRenderer and ShadowMapPlugin handle visibility differently, since they were showing up in the regular render, but not in light's shadow camera renderer. Could that be considered a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Since your hierarchy is 20 levels deep you need to traverse your Meshes in order to set the `.castShadow` and `.receiveShadow` on all levels.

```
object.travese( function( child )
{
    if( child instanceof THREE.Object3D )
    {
        child.castShadow = true;
        child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
} );
```

Comment: since `THREE.Mesh` inherits from `THREE.Object3D` change the `instanceof` check with `THREE.Mesh`

Comment: I already do this as I load the scene. Even when I run this `.traverse` command, it doesn't change the lack of shadows.

Comment: I think you need to post one of the problematic models.